# creating a voronoi diagram of 5 points in 5 dimensions

Tags: python, scipy, voronoi, qhull

As the title states, I want to use Voronoi to split a 5-dimensional space into 5 regions, however I cannot seem to achieve the latter with scipy.

Is my reasoning that this should be possible incorrect or is scipy not allowing this?

This is the code that leads to the error:

```
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi
import numpy as np

dimension = 5
points = 5
points = np.random.uniform(-5, 5, (points, dimension))

voro = Voronoi(points)
```

The error:
`QhullError: QH6214 qhull input error: not enough points(5) to construct initial simplex (need 7)`

Comment: What code generates the error?

Comment: Points are generated uniformly with: `np.random.uniform(-5, 5, (n, d))` where `n=5` and `d=5` and the error is throw using `voronoi = Voronoi(points)`

Comment: The request was more to update your post to show the [mcve] for this. You already mention what code you use, but not in a simple single code block that folks can just copy-paste.

Comment: edited to comply, thanks for the info

Comment: My understanding of higher-dimensional Voronoi diagrams is spotty, but the error message suggests you haven't supplied enough points to compute a (unique?) Voronoi diagram in 5 dimensions.